# Будет ли деструктор виртуальным при объявлении default? C++

Tags: c++, наследование, деструктор, virtual

Прочитав о полезности виртуальных деструкторов пришел к выводу, что лучше всегда деструктор объявлять виртуальным и взять это за правило. Однако столкнулся с интересным вопросом. А что будет, если в классе определен деструктор, так:

```
virtual ~MyDestructor() noexcept = default;
```

Если не ошибаюсь, то генерируемые деструкторы по умолчанию будут виртуальными только в том случае, если деструктор базового класса тоже виртуальный. А что происходит с деструкторами базового класса, объявлены таким образом? Будут ли они сгенерированы автоматически и будут ли они виртуальными? Да и вообще, стоит ли так делать?

Comment: деструкторы наследников без указания виртуальности "скопирует" состояние предка. По умолчанию, деструкторы уже noexcept (если только нет переменных класса, которые нарушают это). Так что для базового класса, нужно писать virtual явно, если оно нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim да я так и написал. Наверное неправильно выразил свою мысль. Будет ли автогенерироваться деструктор, если к нему добавить `virtual` и `=default`? Если будет, то будет ли игнорироваться `virtual`? Класс базовый

Comment: будет генерироваться, игнорироваться не  будет. с чего ему бы это делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, будет сгенерирован *виртуальный* деструктор по умолчанию.

Хотите — проверьте сами, код ведь тривиальный:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Der: public Base
{
    ~Der() { cout << "Yes!!"; }
};

int main()
{
    Base * b = new Der;
    delete b;
}
```

Если деструктор не будет генерироваться — будет ошибка линковки, если не виртуальный — *Yes!!* вы не увидите :)